# Testing Firebase HTTP Cloud functions locally using a query string with GET

Tags: node.js, firebase, testing, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a HTTP Cloud function on Firebase. I can successfully invoke the functions following this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) with GET methods without query strings.

```
> test.get()
```

My question is how do I test HTTP function with query strings? How do I pass it to the invocation call?

I tried this on the shell

```
> test.get({"name":"test"})
```

and on my index.js I tried to print the name:

```
exports.test= functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.name);
});
```

It did not work and returned `undefined`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation you cited says this:

> For invoking HTTPS functions in the shell, usage is the same as the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) NPM module, but replace request with the name of the function you want to emulate.

Notice the link to the documentation for the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module.  You will have to use its APIs for making the test request.  On that linked page, the more specific documentation you're looking for is here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback

What you want to pay attention to is the properties for the first argument called "options".  This object has a lot of potential properties that affect the request.  To send a query string, you should use the `qs` property, like this:

```
test.get({ qs:{ name:"foo" } })
```

This will set the `name` query string parameter to `foo` for the test invocation.

Comment: interesting. it works. I am quite new to node, I assumed it was going to be straightforward. Thanks a lot!